# Showing continuity

Tags: general-topology, continuity

$\begin{gather}
\tilde{H}\colon X\times I \to Y\times I\\
\tilde{H}(x,t) = (H(x,t),t)
\end{gather}$

and we assume $H:X \times I \to Y$ is continous. I want to show $\tilde{H}$ is continuous too. How do I do this? I take a subset and show continuous? How does this work please

Answer (score 0):

The topology of $Y \times I$ is the product topology, which is generated by the Cartesian products $U \times V$, where $U \subset Y$ and $V \subset I$ are open sets. To show that $\tilde{H}$ is continuous, it is thus sufficient to show that the pre-image of every such open set $U \times V$ under $\tilde{H}$ is open. These pre-images are given by:

$$\tilde{H}^{-1}(U \times V) = \{(x,t) \in X \times I, H(x,t) \in U \wedge t \in V\} = H^{-1}(U) \cap (X \times V)\,.$$

Now $H^{-1}(U)$ is open by the continuity of $H$ and $X \times V$ is a Cartesian product of open sets, hence open in the product topology of $X \times I$.